# Incorrect labels for bars in bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm taking a biostatistics class and we've been asked to manipulate some data from a CSV into various different types of plots. I'm having issues getting each bar on a bar plot to show the correct categorical variable. I'm following an example the professor provided and not getting what I want. I'm totally new to this, so my apologies for formatting errors.

I've created the dataframe variable and am now trying to plot it as a bar graph (and later on other variables in the CSV as other types of plots). Not sure if I'm providing the code in the correct manner, but here's what I have so far. We're supposed to create a bar plot of PET using the number of cases (number of each pet/type of pet).

This is the data for this particular question. In the CSV it's shown as just the type of pet each student has (not sure how to share the CSV, but if it'd help I can post it).

I'm editing the post to show the code I've run to get the plot, and include the CSV info (hope I'm doing this right):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
HW2 = pd.read_csv("/Path/to/file")
HW2Grouped = HW2.groupby('Pet').count()
HW2Grouped['Pet'] = HW2Grouped.index
HW2Grouped.columns = ['Pet', 'Count', 'col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']
%matplotlib inline
HW2bar = HW2Grouped.plot.bar(x = 'Pet', y = 'Count', title = "Pet count for students")
HW2bar.set_xlabel('Pet Type')
t = HW2bar.set_ylabel('Count')
```

This is the data I have to work with (sorry it's just a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/XfRZLRT)).

This is the [bar plot](https://imgur.com/zMKsPvH) I got from the code I ran.

Comment: I am guessing that you brought in the CSV in an inconvenient format. The `HW2Grouped.columns` columns feel wrong to me. Could you add, hm, a few rows of the CSV you started with and the statements you used to import them? 

It is often the case that getting your data into the expected arrangement makes everything easy; slightly nonstandard arrangement means that you have to add more and more fix-up lines and flags as you go.

Comment: @cphlewis how could I do this to show you what I'm working with? All I did before the grouped columns command was import the csv using pandas. The csv file has 6 columns with various variables, some numerical and some categorical. I don't have my computer with me at the moment but I can respond with better detail once I'm back home from work. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that when you added a new column, `Pet`, it became the new last column. Then you renamed columns of the `HW2Grouped`, and the first column (where the results of count aggregation are) was renamed to `Pet`, and the actual `Pet` column became `col_4`.

**Let me now trace back to what appeared to be wrong in the steps you tried — to make it clear what was going on.**

When you grouped your DataFrame with this code:

```
HW2Grouped = HW2.groupby('Pet').count()
```

You received this:

```
     Height  Ice Cream  n of letters  Favorite TA  Minutes to Hometown 
Pet 
Cat       1         1             1            1                   1
Dog      17        17            17           17                  17 
Horse     2         2             2            2                   2  
None      4         4             4            4                   4
```

After you performed adding a new column `Pet` (what you might thought was creating a variable) to `HW2Grouped`, it started to look like this:

```
     Height  Ice Cream  n of letters  Favorite TA  Minutes to Hometown   Pet  
Pet 
Cat       1         1             1             1                    1    Cat
Dog      17        17            17            17                   17    Dog      
Horse     2         2             2             2                    2    Horse     
None      4         4             4             4                    4    None
```

Then, when you changed the `.columns` attribute, your grouped DataFrame became like this:

```
        Pet   Count   col_1   col_2    col_3   col_4
Pet 
Cat       1       1      1       1        1     Cat
Dog      17      17     17      17       17     Dog      
Horse     2       2      2       2        2     Horse     
None      4       4      4       4        4     None
```

Then, when plotting `HW2Grouped`, you passed `Pet` as an `x`, but `Pet` now wasn't there after renaming the columns, it now was the former `Height` column. This led to the wrong bar names.

You may try:

```
%matplotlib inline
HW2bar = HW2Grouped.plot.bar(x = 'col_4', y = 'Count', title = "Pet count for students")
HW2bar.set_xlabel('Pet Type')
t = HW2bar.set_ylabel('Count')
```

I think what you originally intended to do was this (except you didn't indicate the column to perform the `count` on):

```
HW2Grouped = HW2.groupby('Pet')['Pet'].count()
```

However, this won't sort the bars in a descending order.

There is a short way without column additions and renaming, the bars will be sorted:

```
HW2['Pet'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

Comment: While I can't say I 100% understand your entire comment (fairly new at this like I said), I think that makes sense. Why would it have done that though? Also, I had to include empty columns (in the Rename variables section) because it was giving me a value mismatch error (said something like 2 vs 6 values mismatch). If it made a new column with the value count, wouldn't that have yielded another values mismatch error? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I tried doing both things you said and they both worked. With your first change, it just added the right labels to the plot I had made before. With your second suggestion, it gave me a new plot with values going from largest to smallest. It's exactly what I needed, so thank you so much! But I still don't really understand what's going on. I'm sorry. If you wouldn't mind explaining more, or if you could point me to a good video/book/something else to learn more about how to go about doing this, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I somehow got the plot to be labeled properly on my own. This is what I did:

%matplotlib inline
HW2_bar = HW2Grouped['Pet'].plot.bar(x = 'Pet', y = 'Count', title = "Pet type by student")
HW2_bar.set_xlabel("Pet type")
t = bar1.set_ylabel("Count")

I added the ['Pet'] to the code for HW2bar, and now it's displaying the labels properly under each bar. I'm glad I came to a solution but I still don't understand what's going on. Sorry for all the comments.

Comment: I would be glad to elaborate on each of your questions, as I am rather new to this too and I've been there where you are now.

First of all, there are multiple solutions to your problem, more convenient and versatile, that can be found either in `pandas` or in many additional modules that concern working with plots. Take a look at [seaborn.countplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) for example. Don't hesitate to search for how to do things right here at stackoverflow just like I've always been doing — you may find many elegant solutions that already exist.

Comment: Secondly, about what was going on with you initial code. When you group by a category and then aggregate with a function, it applies to every column in the dataframe, unless you indicate the columns you want. In your case, the dataframe was grouped by `Pet` and then every occurrence belonging to each pet type was counted in every column. E.g. a column with the number of shots given to a pet would still result in pet type count. In your case, it doesn't make much sense for `count`, but would be totally reasonable for `mean` or `sum`, s it would show mean or sum of shots to each pet type.

Comment: Renaming columns did the renaming itself, but it didn't change the contents of the columns. Had you applied `mean` to the grouped dataframe and renamed columns the similar way that you did in `HW2Grouped.columns` — you would have got, say, the mean height of each pet type instead of the mean pet type count in the `Height` column. Renaming the columns mislead you to what these columns actually were. I would recommend printing out and see what was changed in your data. Particularly about categorical counts you may use `.value_counts()` method. As methods can be chained, you may plot its result.

Comment: @Nelson, I have recreated your dataset and updated the answer with screenshots to illustrate your steps and what was going wrong, hope this was helpful!

Comment: @NelsonBadia, could you please accept my answer (the green tick) if it was helpful to you? It is a common practice here and it is beneficial to both of us. Sorry for asking!

Comment: this was such a helpful explanation. Thank you SO much for this! This makes SO much more sense now. I'll gladly accept your answer. Thank you so much and have a great day!